# Question concerning assumptions for L'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Here is L'Hospital's rule:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$   and $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b),$   where $-\infty \le a<b \le \infty$.   Suppose \begin{equation}
> \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\to A\in [-\infty,\infty]~\hbox{as}~x \to a. 
> \end{equation}
>   If $f(x)\to 0~\hbox{and}~g(x)\to 0 ~\hbox{as}~x \to a,$
>   or if $g(x)\to \infty ~\hbox{as}~x \to a,$
>   then
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to A~\hbox{as}~x \to a
> \end{equation}
>   The analogous statement is also true if $x \to b,$ or if $g(x)\to -\infty$.

I know the condition $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ is necessary. For example, consider $f(x)=x+\sin x \cos x$ and $g(x)=f(x)e^{\sin x}$. Then $\displaystyle\not \exists\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}(=e^{-\sin x})$   and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=\infty$.   However,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}  &=& \frac{2\cos^2 x}{2\cos^2 x e^{\sin x} + (x+\sin x \cos x)\cos x e^{\sin x}}  \\
&=& \frac{2\cos x}{2 \cos x +x+\sin x \cos x} e^{-\sin x}, 
\end{eqnarray*}
which tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

I was wondering if there are other ways to avoid the condition $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. What condition can be replaced with it?

Please let me know if you have any comment for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: good question; cumbersome example. Is there any other function that exhibits the same properties with less terms / visual pollution?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I didn't understand your comment exactly. My mother language is not English. Sorry for that. Anyway, in my opinion, $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ have same term, so that they cancel out. Thus we can get the result L'Hospital's rule fail. I don't know if it is right answer for your comment.

Comment: Ah, sorry friend $\ddot\smile$ I meant, a more simple example would make a nicer question for people to answer $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor  I don’t know if there is a simple example for the same properties. It seems difficult to find simple one.

Comment: This is essentially the "famous" example of Stolz: $f(x) = \int_0^x \cos^2( t )\, dt, \,\,\, g(x) = f(x) \exp(\sin x)$. I've not seen a simpler example. More challenging is to produce an example for limits as $x$ approaches a finite number.

Comment: First of all note that domain of $g'$ is an interval and since it occurs in denominator we must ensure that it does not vanish if we want to talk about $f'/g'$. In other words since one is dealing with ratio $f'/g'$ and its limit, the non-vanishing of $g'$ is implicitly assumed. Some authors explicitly state this to avoid confusion.

Comment: I haven't given any thought to your question, but I thought I'd point out that I posted some references to various generalizations of L'Hopital's rule in this [17 December 2007 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6039558) archived at Math Forum. (See also [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6038222).)